# Мог ли администратор запретить брать со своего сайта информацию с пом. file_get_contents() ?

Tags: php, файлы, get

```
 $x=file_get_contents('http://forum3.ru/cgi/shop/ishop.pl?cmd=show_tovar&code=87661&xhr=1');
echo $x;
```

Перестал выводить что либо(

Мог ли администратор запретить брать со своего сайта информацию с пом. file_get_contents() ?

Comment: C денвера этот запрос работает... 
На другой сайт с хостинга этот запрос работает...

А с хоста на этот сайт выдает пустоту

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, такое возможно, в php,ini можно разрешать и запрещать открытие "файлов" по http протоколу, пишите в сапорт...

Или вы имеете введу сайт с которого вы инфу тянете? если так - нет...

Comment: Почему же нет?) IP, Referer, первый-раз-установка-куки...)

Но в данном случае вряд ли дело в этом, согласен

Comment: <small><b>Sh4dow</b> решил поумничать?:)<br>и перед тем как писать я проверил...</small>

Comment: Ну у меня такая установка, что каждый вопрос тут - для будущих поколений в том числе, потому строгий ответ на поставленный вопрос - "да, мог, но не в вашем случае". Считайте уточнением к вашему ответу)

И плюс в качестве символа мирных намерений))

Comment: Да я же непротив :)<br>
Там где мало file_get_contents - юзается curl ^^<br>
Все-равно информацию не спрячешь... Можно понавыдумывать геморроя всякого но в итоге все-равно парсится все что угодно...

Comment: а есть мысли - в чём собственно дело? Просто работал, работал скрипт, а потом рраз и выдает пустоту....

Comment: Не имею ни малейшего понятия, у меня на локалке все работает без проблем... Как вариант - я написал выше, что админ поменял настройки и написал вам чтобы вы писали в сапорт...